# Working for a company based in Paris remotely from Sri Lanka

Tags: international, labor-law, france, international-court-of-justice

I'm Sri Lankan, I live in Sri Lanka and I'm going to have a remote job in a Paris company(It'll end up my current job contract at next year July, which I bond to the Paris company by a Secondment agreement. After, the Paris company asks me to work for them directly).
Are there any legal issues that would prevent me to do so? How would they calculate my wage? In this case, do my Paris employer bond to the minimum wage law(labor-law) in France? Are there any tricky things I should know about this situation?

Comment: They will most likely engage you as an independent contractor, in which case your biggest headache is probably going to be figuring out the Sri Lankan bureaucracy -- should you incorporate, what taxes do you owe, etc.  The French minimum wage would not apply because you are not working in France.

Comment: "How would they calculate my wage?" However the contract of employment says. The other questions are much more challenging.